# How to create a step method

Tags: android

I want to schedule a method to handle my application logic in a game-y way. In game engines there's usually a schedule/enqueue to add scheduled children to any given scene. A scheduled method is one that is run usually on a separate thread a fixed number of times a second (if possible) and takes care of the application state (log in, log out, idle) and all operations related to said state.

What is the Android equivalent of this for an Activity?

Comment: Your question is a little vague, can you give a bit more detail to exactly what you want to do? Maybe you are trying to schedule something on the next available UI thread (add/remove UI?) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable) Or you just want to generically schedule something for the future?

Comment: I have a map view, and I have several dots that have to be placed here and there depending on a machine state and a couple of listeners (GPS). I want a method that changes the position values of the dots, or maybe show an alert depending on a state or a request, but outside the draw/map invalidation methods.

Rethinking about it maybe a observer pattern should suffice, but I still would like to know how to do it.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you need something like `AsyncTask`.  It runs on a separate thread, but has a hook for updating UI whenever necessary.

Comment: AsyncTasks are not meant to be be scheduled.


From the documentation: "If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the java.util.concurrent package such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask."